# leafletjs, 2gis, мультиязычность

Tags: leafletjs

Прикручиваю к сайту мультиязычность, в связи с чем возникла необходимость изменить язык карты 2gis (используется совместно с leafletjs). Каким образом можно изменить язык этой связки?

Comment: В чем конкретно проблема? Что пробовали? Что получилось? Что не получилось? `map.setLang('en');` пробовали?

Comment: map.setLang('en') - в консоле тишина, язык остается русским. map.locale.setLang('en') - Cannot read property 'setLang' of undefined, что логично